# How to use constantcontact/php-sdk in magento 2.1.1?

Tags: magento2, module, api

I tried use ti contant contact SDK in magento2 but not success.

This code:

```
$path = pathinfo($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);

require_once __DIR__ .'/php-sdk-master/src/Ctct/autoload.php';
require_once $path['dirname'].'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Ctct\ConstantContact;
use Ctct\Components\Contacts\Contact;
use Ctct\Exceptions\CtctException;

public function addContacts($memberData)
    {   
        $apiKey = $this->getApiKey();
        $accessToken = $this->getAccessToken();
        $email = $memberData['email_address'];
        $list = $memberData['list'];
        $cc = new ConstantContact($apiKey);

        // attempt to fetch lists in the account, catching any exceptions and printing the errors to screen
        try {
            $lists = $cc->listService->getLists($accessToken);
        } catch (CtctException $ex) {
            foreach ($ex->getErrors() as $error) {
                print_r($error);
            }
            if (!isset($lists)) {
                $lists = null;
            }
        }
            $action = "Getting Contact By Email Address";
            try {
                // check to see if a contact with the email address already exists in the account
                $response = $cc->contactService->getContacts($accessToken, array("email" => $email));

                // create a new contact if one does not exist
                if (empty($response->results)) {
                    $action = "Creating Contact";

                    $contact = new Contact();
                    $contact->addEmail($email);
                    $contact->addList($list);
                    $contact->first_name = "";
                    $contact->last_name = "";

                    /*
                     * The third parameter of addContact defaults to false, but if this were set to true it would tell Constant
                     * Contact that this action is being performed by the contact themselves, and gives the ability to
                     * opt contacts back in and trigger Welcome/Change-of-interest emails.
                     *
                     * See: http://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/contacts-api/contacts-index.html#opt_in
                     */
                    $returnContact = $cc->contactService->addContact($accessToken, $contact);

                    // update the existing contact if address already existed
                } else {
                    $action = "Updating Contact";

                    $contact = $response->results[0];
                    if ($contact instanceof Contact) {
                        $contact->addList($list);
                        $contact->first_name = '';
                        $contact->last_name = '';

                        /*
                         * The third parameter of updateContact defaults to false, but if this were set to true it would tell
                         * Constant Contact that this action is being performed by the contact themselves, and gives the ability to
                         * opt contacts back in and trigger Welcome/Change-of-interest emails.
                         *
                         * See: http://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/contacts-api/contacts-index.html#opt_in
                         */
                        $returnContact = $cc->contactService->updateContact($accessToken, $contact);
                    } else {
                        $e = new CtctException();
                        $e->setErrors(array("type", "Contact type not returned"));
                        throw $e;
                    }
                }

                // catch any exceptions thrown during the process and print the errors to screen
            } catch (CtctException $ex) {
                echo '<span class="label label-important">Error ' . $action . '</span>';
                echo '<div class="container alert-error"><pre class="failure-pre">';
                print_r($ex->getErrors());
                echo '</pre></div>';
                die();
            }
        print_r($response); die();
        return $response;
    }
```

after i get message `Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found in ...\php-sdk-master\src\Ctct\Services\BaseService.php`

i tried get source `https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle` but not run.

Pls help me how to  require GuzzleHttp\Client in my source.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use composer to add `constantcontact/constantcontact` as dependensies for you module/magento app": composer require  "constantcontact/constantcontact:2.1.*"

After this you no need use custom autoloader (require_once **DIR** .'/php-sdk-master/src/Ctct/autoload.php';)

Comment: Thanks @Kandy In my source has folder standalone/vendor zip. I extract it and `require_once __DIR__ .'/php-sdk-master/src/Ctct/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ .'/php-sdk-master/standalone/vendor/autoload.php';` in file then it  good work.

Comment: thank's, i'm still confused about how/where to use require_once(autloader), mine is simple handmade script that loads statically every needed file (not much), I tried in registration.php but it causes a login issue (admin and front) and don't know how to debug it